# Select rows of pandas dataframe based on column values with duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like this

```
   customer_id  some_data
0      1            A
1      2            B
2      3            C  
3      1            D
```

and a list of customer_id values with duplicates for example [1,2,2]. Based on these values I want to get a dataframe in which customer_id equal to a value in the list, but if I get a duplicate value in the list, I want duplicate values in rows, for example for [1,2,2] my output should be

```
   customer_id  some_data
 0     1            A
 3     1            D
 1     2            B
 1     2            B
```

I tried something like this

```
df_new= df[df.customer_id == list[0]]
for i in range(1,len(list)):
    temp = df[df.customer_id == list[i]]
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, temp])
```

This code works but mine df is large so the working time of this code is large, can I optimize it somehow?

Comment: `df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,2,2]}, on='customer_id')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create another dummy dataframe with the ids you wish to have:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,2,2]})

    customer_id
0   1
1   2
2   2
```

and merge it with the give dataframe:

```
df.merge(df2)
```

desired result:

```
 customer_id    some_data
0   1            A
1   1            D
2   2            B
3   2            B
```

Most importantly: your code will work but its very slow for large data. The reason for your long processing time is your **for loop!** to optimize it you should always aim at vectorizing.